# git conflict notation not showing

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-rerere

I received a conflict when trying to merge two files:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in user.py
```

When I looked into user.py, there is no git-conflict-notation/mark that I was used to:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
Hello world
=======
Hola mundo
>>>>>>>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is this file compiled or concatenated? Sometimes the conflict is resolved by the build system after files change.

Comment: Well I have to resolve the conflict manually. The system isn't resolving it.

Comment: Do you have git-rerere enabled? (look at `git config rerere.enabled`)

Comment: Yes I do! Is that the problem?
edit: For others that may have the same question: I set git rerere to false and now the notation is showing! Thanks @sehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess was you might have git-rerere enabled.

- [Rerere your boat...](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html)
- [man git-rerere](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere)

This facility [re]cords [re]solutions to past conflicts. So next time you merge or rebase the same topic branch into a (very) similar (revision of) a branch, then git [re]members which conflict resolutions you picked and applies them for you.

This is awesome if you use topic branches or frequent rebasing.

However, should you need/prefer total control, disable it:

```
git config rerere.enabled false
```